# Restricted Kubernetes Service account

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I want to create a service account which should have 0 access of k8s api. 
Is it possible to create such account ? What will be role definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to define a Role like this:

```yaml
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: nothing
rules: []
```

Create it:

```
kubectl apply -f nothing.yaml
```

Then bind it to your ServiceAccount:

```
kubectl create rolebinding nothing --serviceaccount my-serviceaccount --role nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Kubernetes follows the principle of least priviledge.If you create a service account but don't attach any role binding or cluster role binding to it then it will not have any access to Kubernetes API.

Comment: This. RoleBindings only ever add more effective permissions, you start from 0 (give or take permissions granted to some magic roles but few people use that system).